# Get Parent element from child element in appium

Tags: appium

I have a recycler view. All Rows have same ids. Each Row has checkbox and text and these elements also have same ids. But some rows does not have checkboxes.

So what i am trying to do is locate checkbox by id, then get its parent node and locate its child.

```
MobileElement childElement= driver.findElement(By.id("checkbox-child"));
MobileElement parentElement= // need to know how to do it 

parentElement.findElement(By.id("text-child")).getText();
```

So i wanted to know how can i get parent element from its child Element.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An overlay of one way I could think of solving this is :

```java
List<WebElement> listParent = driver.findElements(By.id("parentID")); //Requires parent's resource-id.
for(int i=0;i<listParent.size();i++){
    String parentXPath = "//android.widget.RelativeLayout["+i+"]"
    String childXPath = parentXPath + "//android.widget.Checkbox"; //should get you the child corresponding to the specific Relative Layout
    MobileElement parentElement= driver.findElement(By.XPath(parentXPath); 
    if(isElementPresent(By.XPath(childXPath))){
       parentElement.findElement(By.id("text-child")).getText();
    }
```

Would try this on my end as well.

Comment: Thanks for an idea. Unfortunately above code did not work . But i think if i put more efforts on your idea, i can solve it :) Cheers !